# Change page size of Pageable(spring boot jpa)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I´m working showing some info on a table and I´m using `@PageableDefault(size = Constants.PAGE_SIZE) Pageable pageable` to determine the size of the page im showing(5 elements at the moment).

The point here is that I want to be able to change the value of that page size using a `<select>` to be able to modify the page size in my controller and redirect it into my table endpoint:

```
@PostMapping("/size")
public String size(){
    //Constants.PAGE_SIZE;
    return "redirect:/users/showusers";
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass page request like this, pass your size variable in page request.

```
PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(0, 5);  //or default
```

use below to pass page size dynamically..

```
PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(0, size);
```

in repository method pass `Pageable pageable`